# Highlight Excel Cells Related to Two Different Multiple Values

Tags: excel, highlight, cells

Have a problem to solve. I am creating a file with category ID’s (numeric) and have different specification fields for each category, some of them are the same some are changing depending on category ID.

Let's say:

I have category ID’s for cell A2 (cat id: 111),  A3 (cat id: 222), A4 - (cat id: 333) and so on.

Category “111” contain specifications like: Price; Condition; Size; Colour; Brand.

Category “222” contain specifications like: Price; Condition; Brand; Manufacture; Shape; Model.
Category “333”  ………

My list looks like that:

A1-Cat ID   B1-Price    C1-Cond. D1-Size E1-Colour  F1-Brand G1-Colour H1-Manufacture I1-Shape J- Model

A2-111

A3-222

A4-333

As you can see I have a list of specifications and different category ID’s related to a particular specification. 
My question is: how can I highlight cells of each specification which is related only to particular ID. I have about 40 specifications and 15 different  ID’s so it is frustrating every time scroll through the rows, remember ID that you work with and follow separate specifications sheet related to ID’s? Specifications must stay in a list all the time, leave empty cell if doesn’t match with ID.

Not sure if this is the best way so if any of you guys have other options to consider, please let me know.

Thank a lot for any answer and help.

Comment: Does Conditional Formatting not work? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Haven't tried but does a condition formatting stays after files is closed and reopened?

Comment: Yep - it stays with the document.